# Checks if a string ends with a specific word in php?

Tags: php, regex

There are many questions like this question but I can not find exact answer.  And I am unfamiliar Regular Expresion topic.

I wanted to know if `$variable` ends with "books".

For example :

```
$variable = "some-historical-books".
```

So, I will display books page if it ends with books.

Thank you.

Comment: PHP 8.0 introduces new method for this job `str_end_with`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/64160081/7082164

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe you should look into [a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). What you are looking for is [an anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), that marks the end of the string.

```
if(preg_match('/books$/', $variable))
    // redirect to books page
```

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is to add the word you need and a `$` at the end of your regex

```
$pattern = "/books$/";
```

Just like if you want to find out if your value starts with a specific string, you can use `^` at the beginning :

```
$pattern = "/^Books/";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't definiteley need regex here:

```
<?php
$variable = "some-historical-books";
$searchterm = "books";

$pos = strrpos($variable, $searchterm);

if ($pos !== false && strlen($searchterm) + $pos == strlen($variable))
    echo "yep, it's at the end";
```

Comment: This is not right, if the needle is found in the middle of the string, it will return true when you specified to be exactly at the end.